# Jquery cycle plugin containerResize option

Tags: jquery, slideshow, cycle

Im using jquery cycle on have a fade slideshow like so...

```
$('.pics').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    timeout:5000,
    random: 1,
    containerResize: false
});
```

it was working fine before but since I added `containerResize: false` my images wont show up anymore...does anyone know what its doing this?...example at http://willruppelglass.com/index.php

here is some other code, might help, never know....

```
.pics {  

    padding: 0;  
    margin:  0;
} 

.pics img {    
    background-color: #eee;  
    height: 200px; 
    text-align:center;
    top:  0; 
    left: 0;
}

.contentImages{
    border:1px solid #CCC; 
    padding:10px; 
    margin:20px auto 0; 
    position:relative;
    width: 600px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

<div class="contentImages">

<div class="pics">

<img src="upload/<?php echo $array['image'] ?>" height="200" />

<img src="upload/<?php echo $array['image2'] ?>" height="200" />

<img src="upload/<?php echo $array['image3'] ?>" height="200" />

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You either need to keep `containerResize: true` or set a `height` or `min-height` on `.contentImages`. You are hiding all overflow on an element with 0 height, its children will never show. Inspecting your DOM will show you that.